# Confusion about calculus of variations

Tags: analysis, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I am currently struggling with variational calculus and hope for some clarification.

The goal of variational calculus is to find a specific path/function $y(x)$, for which the integral

> $I[q] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(y(x),y'(x),x) dx$

either has a maximum or a minimum. In order to find this specific path, we introduce

> $\tilde{y}(x) = y(x) + \epsilon \eta(x)$,

with the additional contraint $\eta(x_1) = \eta(x_2) = 0$. Using this information, we can introduce

> $I_{\eta}[q] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(y(x)+\epsilon \eta(x),y'(x)+\epsilon \eta'(x),x) dx$.

In order that the integral $I$ has an extremum for the path $y(x)$,

> $\frac{dI}{d\epsilon}\vert_{\epsilon = 0} = 0$

must be true. The expression above naturally leads to the Euler-Lagrange-equations:

> $\frac{dI}{d\epsilon}\vert_{\epsilon = 0} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \Big( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \Big)\eta(x) dx$.

My question is wether the displacements $\eta(x)$ can only be equal to zero for $x = x_1$ and $x = x_2$ or also for any $x_n \in (x_1,x_2)$, since I am not sure, wether the latter case also produces the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: The displacement eta is equal to zero at the boarder so that the perturbed function respects some boundary conditions I guess. Nothing is said about what values it should have inside the domain, in particular it can in theory be identically zero. But the powerfulness of the approach is that eta is as generic as possible, to derive than the Euler-Lagrange equations.